# Can I play the song or music piece that I don’t write?

Tags: copyrights

Can I play or sing the song that I don’t own? Is there any law related to the rights to play and sing a song when you are with friends or at home?

Comment: It may well depend on the laws in your country, which we can only guess.

Comment: @Tim sorry, Iam Vietnamese and I am currently living in Việt Nam. :))

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because business and legal questions are off topic as outlined in the help center.

Comment: Welcome! You can read about the [topics that are covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). In this case, even though it has to do with music, this is a question about law. You could try asking at https://law.stackexchange.com/ (though you should specify the context of Vietnam). Also, I think it might matter just how many "friends" there are, or if you charge admission, or if you record the music-making, etc. Being in your own house probably matters very little.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Thank your for pointing the mistake in my question.

Comment: @AndyBonner Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play and sing any song you like. In case the piece is not considered PD but intellectual property of a (or multiple) person or legal entity you will need a license to publicly perform the work, publishing recordings the work, publish sheet music of the work and such. What you do in a private context is not regulated by copyright laws (although these depends on which jurisdiction you live in).

Comment: I'd still defer to the legal SE; my perception is it's not so much about public/private as about charging admission. A "house concert" that charges admission is not necessarily "anything goes."

Comment: @AndyBonner Yes, if legal things get too involved  this is definitely not something that can or should be acquired here. Of course with house concerts it is a bit of a grey zone, for when exactly is something not private anymore, but public? But as I understand the OP it is not about giving anything like a house concert.

Comment: idk how far this travels internationally [though UK & EU tend to be similar, idk outside that] You need no license to perform any song live. The **venue** needs a license, from which 'unreported revenue' is paid to writers, not based on logging the actual performances. Your home would not require any license.

Comment: @Tetsujin To be more exact, the  organizer of the concert needs a license to have the piece publicly performed. The organizer can very well be the player.

Comment: @Lazy - not in the UK. The venue needs the license; it's on an annual basis. They don't advertise costs, you have to get a quote - https://pplprs.co.uk The actual piece[s] performed do not need to be reported. These are blanket licenses to cut down on admin. It used to be that every gig you played you had to fill in a sheet of exactly which songs were performed.. of course very very few ever bothered so the system didn't work.

Comment: @Tetsujin That’s an interesting approach. So if I rented a concert hall in the UK and organized a concert there then the hall owner would need to pay the fees?

Comment: The hall would already be licensed, yes, for the other 200 gigs they run this year. As a performer, it's not even really your job to check their license is in place - though there's a facility to report those who aren't.

Comment: @Tetsujin Wow, that is quite a pragmatic approach!

Comment: @Lazy - it works, for a given definition of 'works'. The old system only worked for radio, who were compelled to send playlists [& so ended up working deals with publishers to play 'tracks they didn't need to report'] The structure collapsed long before this all could have been done far more easily by computerised systems.